# how to create a confusion matrix for xgboost in R

Tags: r, xgboost, xgbclassifier

I have already created my XGBoost classifier in R as in below code

```
#importing the dataset
XGBoostDataSet_Hr_Admin_8 <- read.csv("CompletedDataImputed_HR_Admin.csv")

#Use factor function to convert categorical data to numerical data
XGBoostDataSet_Hr_Admin_8$Salary = as.numeric(factor(XGBoostDataSet_Hr_Admin_8$Salary, levels =c('L','M', 'H', 'V'), labels =c(1,2,3,4)))
XGBoostDataSet_Hr_Admin_8$Rude_Behavior = as.numeric(factor(XGBoostDataSet_Hr_Admin_8$Rude_Behavior, levels=c('Y', 'M', 'N'), labels =c(1,2,3)))
XGBoostDataSet_Hr_Admin_8$Feeling_undervalued =as.numeric(factor(XGBoostDataSet_Hr_Admin_8$Feeling_undervalued, levels=c('Y', 'M', 'N'), labels =c(1,2,3)))
XGBoostDataSet_Hr_Admin_8$Overall_satisfaction = as.numeric(factor(XGBoostDataSet_Hr_Admin_8$Overall_satisfaction, levels=c('Y', 'M', 'N'), labels =c(1,2,3)))
XGBoostDataSet_Hr_Admin_8$Raises_frozen = as.numeric(factor(XGBoostDataSet_Hr_Admin_8$Raises_frozen, levels=c('Y', 'M', 'N'), labels =c(1,2,3)))
XGBoostDataSet_Hr_Admin_8$Poor_Conditions = as.numeric(factor(XGBoostDataSet_Hr_Admin_8$Poor_Conditions, levels=c('Y', 'M', 'N'), labels =c(1,2,3)))
XGBoostDataSet_Hr_Admin_8$Growth_not_available = as.numeric(factor(XGBoostDataSet_Hr_Admin_8$Growth_not_available, levels=c('Y', 'M', 'N'), labels =c(1,2,3)))
XGBoostDataSet_Hr_Admin_8$Workplace_Conflict = as.numeric(factor(XGBoostDataSet_Hr_Admin_8$Workplace_Conflict, levels=c('Y', 'M', 'N'), labels =c(1,2,3)))
XGBoostDataSet_Hr_Admin_8$Employee_Turnover = as.numeric(factor(XGBoostDataSet_Hr_Admin_8$Employee_Turnover, levels=c('Y', 'N'), labels =c(1,0)))

#split the data in train dataset and test dataset
library(caTools)
split = sample.split(XGBoostDataSet_Hr_Admin_8$Employee_Turnover,SplitRatio = 0.7)
training_set8 = subset(XGBoostDataSet_Hr_Admin_8, split==TRUE)
test_set8 = subset(XGBoostDataSet_Hr_Admin_8, split==FALSE)

#fitting XGBoost to the Training Test
library(xgboost)
classifier9 = xgboost(data = as.matrix(training_set8[-10]), label = training_set8$Employee_Turnover, nrounds = 10)
```

Now, I need to create a confusion matrix for the XGBoost.

I have searched on the net and unfortunately can't find the solution.

Can anyone please help me out.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things to note, you need to convert your training_set8$Employee_Turnover to 0s and 1s. Hopefully you have done that, if not see my example below.

Second, you need to specify, objective = "binary:logistic" when doing xgboost, this does classification.

So starting with what you have:

```
library(caTools)
library(xgboost)
library(caret)
set.seed(12345)
# reproducible results

XGBoostDataSet_Hr_Admin_8 <- read.csv("CompletedDataImputed_HR_Admin.csv")

#Use factor function to convert categorical data to numerical data
XGBoostDataSet_Hr_Admin_8$Salary = as.numeric(factor(XGBoostDataSet_Hr_Admin_8$Salary, levels =c('L','M', 'H', 'V'), labels =c(1,2,3,4)))
XGBoostDataSet_Hr_Admin_8$Rude_Behavior = as.numeric(factor(XGBoostDataSet_Hr_Admin_8$Rude_Behavior, levels=c('Y', 'M', 'N'), labels =c(1,2,3)))
XGBoostDataSet_Hr_Admin_8$Feeling_undervalued =as.numeric(factor(XGBoostDataSet_Hr_Admin_8$Feeling_undervalued, levels=c('Y', 'M', 'N'), labels =c(1,2,3)))
XGBoostDataSet_Hr_Admin_8$Overall_satisfaction = as.numeric(factor(XGBoostDataSet_Hr_Admin_8$Overall_satisfaction, levels=c('Y', 'M', 'N'), labels =c(1,2,3)))
XGBoostDataSet_Hr_Admin_8$Raises_frozen = as.numeric(factor(XGBoostDataSet_Hr_Admin_8$Raises_frozen, levels=c('Y', 'M', 'N'), labels =c(1,2,3)))
XGBoostDataSet_Hr_Admin_8$Poor_Conditions = as.numeric(factor(XGBoostDataSet_Hr_Admin_8$Poor_Conditions, levels=c('Y', 'M', 'N'), labels =c(1,2,3)))
XGBoostDataSet_Hr_Admin_8$Growth_not_available = as.numeric(factor(XGBoostDataSet_Hr_Admin_8$Growth_not_available, levels=c('Y', 'M', 'N'), labels =c(1,2,3)))
XGBoostDataSet_Hr_Admin_8$Workplace_Conflict = as.numeric(factor(XGBoostDataSet_Hr_Admin_8$Workplace_Conflict, levels=c('Y', 'M', 'N'), labels =c(1,2,3)))
```

For this part, we set the labels correctly as 0 and 1

```
#set levels
lvl = c('N', 'Y')
# sorry I have to do it like this, it's too long for me to read
lb = as.character(XGBoostDataSet_Hr_Admin_8$Employee_Turnover)
lb = as.numeric(factor(lb,levels=lvl))-1
XGBoostDataSet_Hr_Admin_8$Employee_Turnover = lb
```

And we do the split into train + test as you have:

```
#split the data in train dataset and test dataset
split = sample.split(XGBoostDataSet_Hr_Admin_8$Employee_Turnover,SplitRatio = 0.7)
training_set8 = subset(XGBoostDataSet_Hr_Admin_8, split==TRUE)
test_set8 = subset(XGBoostDataSet_Hr_Admin_8, split==FALSE)
```

Do the fit:

```
#fitting XGBoost to the Training Test
classifier9 = xgboost(data = as.matrix(training_set8[-10]), 
label = training_set8$Employee_Turnover, nrounds = 10)
```

Now we get the prediction in terms of probability and convert

```
pred <- predict(classifier9, as.matrix(training_set8[-10]))
# we convert to predicted labels
pred_label <- lvl[as.numeric(pred>0.5)+1]
# we get the observed label, or iris$Species
actual_label <- lvl[as.numeric(training_set8$Employee_Turnover)+1]
```

Last confusion matrix:

```
# confusion matrix
table(pred_label,actual_label)
          actual_label
pred_label   N   Y
         N  41   0
         Y   0 158
```

Or using caret:

```
confusionMatrix(factor(pred_label,levels=lvl),
factor(actual_label,levels=lvl))
    Confusion Matrix and Statistics

              Reference
    Prediction   N   Y
             N  41   0
             Y   0 158
```

This is the actual data (kindly provided by OP):

```
structure(list(Salary = structure(c(2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("H", "L", "M", "V"), class = "factor"), 
    Percentage_Increment = c(5, 10, 7, 7, 5, 7, 5, 5, 10, 5, 
    5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 10, 5, 5, 10, 10, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
    5, 10, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 10, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 7, 
    5, 5, 10, 7, 5, 5, 5, 5, 10, 10, 10, 5, 5, 5, 7, 10, 5, 5, 
    5, 7, 10, 5, 7, 5, 5, 10, 10, 10, 5, 5, 10, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
    5, 5, 5, 10, 5, 5, 7, 7, 5, 10, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 7, 5, 10, 
    5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 7, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 10, 5, 5, 
    5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 7, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 10, 5, 10, 5, 5, 
    5, 7, 5, 7, 10, 7, 10, 5, 10, 10, 5, 7, 5, 5, 10, 5, 5, 5, 
    10, 5, 7, 5, 5, 5, 5, 10, 3, 5, 5, 10, 10, 5, 5, 7, 10, 5, 
    5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 10, 5, 7, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 7, 5, 7, 5, 5, 
    5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 7, 5, 7, 5, 5, 5, 10, 10, 5, 5, 5, 
    10, 5, 10, 10, 10, 10, 7, 5, 7, 5, 5, 10, 1, 10, 30, 1, 0.02, 
    5, 1, 11, 1, 3, 10, 1, 11, 1, 5, 10, 2.2, 18, 4, 10, 8, 1, 
    5, 9, 5, 4, 15, 15, 4, 10, 12, 1, 9, 3, 2.5, 5, 20, 30, 10, 
    5, 100, 10, 1, 1, 8, 1, 1, 2, 1, 5, 10, 1, 50, 50, 2, 3, 
    25, 1, 1), Rude_Behavior = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 
    3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
    3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
    3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
    3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("M", "N", 
    "Y"), class = "factor"), Feeling_undervalued = structure(c(1L, 
    2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 
    3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
    3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
    3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 
    2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("M", 
    "N", "Y"), class = "factor"), Overall_satisfaction = structure(c(2L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
    1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
    3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("M", 
    "N", "Y"), class = "factor"), Poor_Conditions = structure(c(3L, 
    1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
    3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
    3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
    1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
    3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 
    3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 
    3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
    3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("M", 
    "N", "Y"), class = "factor"), Raises_frozen = structure(c(2L, 
    3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
    2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
    2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
    3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
    2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
    2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 
    3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("M", 
    "N", "Y"), class = "factor"), Growth_not_available = structure(c(1L, 
    3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 
    2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
    2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
    3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
    3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
    3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
    3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
    2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
    3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("M", 
    "N", "Y"), class = "factor"), Workplace_Conflict = structure(c(3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
    3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
    2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
    3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
    3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
    3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
    1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("M", 
    "N", "Y"), class = "factor"), Employee_Turnover = structure(c(2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("N", 
    "Y"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-284L))
```

Comment: Here what i've done
XGBoostDataSet_Hr_Admin_8 <- read.csv("CompletedDataImputed_HR_Admin.csv")
XGBoostDataSet_Hr_Admin_8$Salary = as.numeric(factor(XGBoostDataSet_Hr_Admin_8$Salary, levels =c('L','M', 'H', 'V'), labels =c(1,2,3,4)))
library(caTools)
split = sample.split(XGBoostDataSet_Hr_Admin_8$Employee_Turnover,SplitRatio = 0.7)
training_set8 = subset(XGBoostDataSet_Hr_Admin_8, split==TRUE)
test_set8 = subset(XGBoostDataSet_Hr_Admin_8, split==FALSE)
library(xgboost)
classifier9 = xgboost(data = as.matrix(training_set8[-10]), label = training_set8$Employee_Turnover, nrounds = 10)

Comment: can you include this in the question? It's very hard for me to read it in comments

Comment: @ibocus, the problem lies with the label, it's 1s and 2s, not 0s and 1s. I will edit my answer, with some code to try and hopefully solve it

Comment: hey @ibocus, can you try it?

Comment: thanks very much and waiting for your updated code. Between is there any solution regarding converting categorical to numerical labels to fit the xgboost classifier without getting my issue of 1s and 2s

Comment: when fitting XGBoost to the Training Test, am getting this error
Error in xgb.DMatrix(data, label = label, missing = missing) : 
  'data' has class 'character' and length 1791.
  'data' accepts either a numeric matrix or a single filename.

Comment: Hmmm quite weird and I have no clue honestly how you end up with that when previous times work.. Can you share a link to your data or dput it ? It's very hard for all of us to troubleshoot as you can see

Comment: just let me know a platform where i can share the dataset with you

Comment: share a google link or something like that? Haha sorry I seldom share links on SO.. or you do this, dput(head(XGBoostDataSet_Hr_Admin_8,20)), if the output is not too big, paste it in your post

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=11AliKO3E5KoHuv0sXZNPXVeiOSTl9yHR

Comment: try this link...https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/11AliKO3E5KoHuv0sXZNPXVeiOSTl9yHR?usp=sharing

Comment: @ibocus, done.. it wasn't so bad. Next time do dput like I have done, and I think your problem would have been solved in < 30min..Lol

Comment: it works, thanking you very much :), i owe you this

Comment: I'm glad it worked too :) Next time really put the data used for the model. I once made the same mistake like you, so I am always wary of it.

Comment: is it normal that when adding up the numbers of the confusion matrix i get 199 when infact i have 285 records in my dataset?

Comment: @ibocus, you ran the model on the training set, and did the confusion matrix on the training set right. Training set has 199

Comment: You have to predict your test set and see whether it holds.

Comment: you are absolutely right, i just got confused.. thanks a lot for making it crystal clear for me.. thanks :)

Comment: i was just wondering where did you accumulate this huge amount of knowledge, is it possible to share your story

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `caret::confusionMatrix()` function, but you need some work on your output. Clearly you need a vector of the real result (test dataset), to compare the calculated results and the real one:

```
library(xgboost)


#Use factor function to convert categorical data to numerical data
XGBoostDataSet_Hr_Admin_8$Salary = as.numeric(factor(XGBoostDataSet_Hr_Admin_8$Salary, levels =c('L','M', 'H', 'V'), labels =c(1,2,3,4)))
XGBoostDataSet_Hr_Admin_8$Rude_Behavior = as.numeric(factor(XGBoostDataSet_Hr_Admin_8$Rude_Behavior, levels=c('Y', 'M', 'N'), labels =c(1,2,3)))
XGBoostDataSet_Hr_Admin_8$Feeling_undervalued =as.numeric(factor(XGBoostDataSet_Hr_Admin_8$Feeling_undervalued, levels=c('Y', 'M', 'N'), labels =c(1,2,3)))
XGBoostDataSet_Hr_Admin_8$Overall_satisfaction = as.numeric(factor(XGBoostDataSet_Hr_Admin_8$Overall_satisfaction, levels=c('Y', 'M', 'N'), labels =c(1,2,3)))
XGBoostDataSet_Hr_Admin_8$Raises_frozen = as.numeric(factor(XGBoostDataSet_Hr_Admin_8$Raises_frozen, levels=c('Y', 'M', 'N'), labels =c(1,2,3)))
XGBoostDataSet_Hr_Admin_8$Poor_Conditions = as.numeric(factor(XGBoostDataSet_Hr_Admin_8$Poor_Conditions, levels=c('Y', 'M', 'N'), labels =c(1,2,3)))
XGBoostDataSet_Hr_Admin_8$Growth_not_available = as.numeric(factor(XGBoostDataSet_Hr_Admin_8$Growth_not_available, levels=c('Y', 'M', 'N'), labels =c(1,2,3)))
XGBoostDataSet_Hr_Admin_8$Workplace_Conflict = as.numeric(factor(XGBoostDataSet_Hr_Admin_8$Workplace_Conflict, levels=c('Y', 'M', 'N'), labels =c(1,2,3)))
XGBoostDataSet_Hr_Admin_8$Employee_Turnover = as.numeric(factor(XGBoostDataSet_Hr_Admin_8$Employee_Turnover, levels=c('Y', 'N'), labels =c(1,0)))

# here ifelse 0 1
XGBoostDataSet_Hr_Admin_8$Employee_Turnover = ifelse(XGBoostDataSet_Hr_Admin_8$Employee_Turnover == 1,0,1)

library(caTools)


split = sample.split(XGBoostDataSet_Hr_Admin_8$Employee_Turnover,SplitRatio = 0.7)
training_set8 = subset(XGBoostDataSet_Hr_Admin_8, split==TRUE)
test_set8 = subset(XGBoostDataSet_Hr_Admin_8, split==FALSE)

bst <- xgboost(data = as.matrix(training_set8[,-10]), label = training_set8$Employee_Turnover, max_depth = 2,
               eta = 0.5, nthread = 2, nrounds = 5, objective = "binary:logistic")  

# you've to do your prediction here
pred <- predict(bst, as.matrix(test_set8[,-10]))

# and transform them in a 0 1 variable, you can choose the value to get 1
pred <-  as.numeric(pred > 0.5)

library(caret)
confusionMatrix(factor(pred),factor(test_set8$Employee_Turnover))

Confusion Matrix and Statistics

          Reference
Prediction  0  1
         0 67  2
         1  0 16

               Accuracy : 0.9765          
                 95% CI : (0.9176, 0.9971)
    No Information Rate : 0.7882          
    P-Value [Acc > NIR] : 4.626e-07       

                  Kappa : 0.9265          

 Mcnemar's Test P-Value : 0.4795          

            Sensitivity : 1.0000          
            Specificity : 0.8889          
         Pos Pred Value : 0.9710          
         Neg Pred Value : 1.0000          
             Prevalence : 0.7882          
         Detection Rate : 0.7882          
   Detection Prevalence : 0.8118          
      Balanced Accuracy : 0.9444          

       'Positive' Class : 0
```

Comment: Hello s_t,
am getting this error when trying this part 
pred <- predict(classifier8, test_set8$Employee_Turnover ,type = "response")

Error in xgb.DMatrix(newdata, missing = missing) : 
  xgb.DMatrix does not support construction from double

can you please guide me from where I have already generate my classifier as follows
classifier8 = xgboost(data = as.matrix(training_set8[-10]), label = training_set8$Employee_Turnover, nrounds = 10)

Comment: hey s_t and ibocus, I just saw your answer, i think @ibocus did not use xgb.DMatrix like the example, but just fed xgboost a matrix and labels (which I am not sure of)

Comment: i have updated the full script in my question, can you please have a look and see how from there i can create the confusion matrix

Comment: Unluckily without your data is useless (try to post if you can train and test, using `dput()`function, or some fake one similar to yours). However have you tried: `pred <- predict(classifier8, test_set8 ,type = "response") `?

Comment: try your code pred <- predict(classifier8, test_set8 ,type = "response"), however i got this error, "Error in xgb.DMatrix(newdata, missing = missing) : 
  xgb.DMatrix does not support construction from list"

Comment: @s_t, can i know what is the 400 means in the code, i have 284 records in my dataset, should i change this from 400 to 284 and secondly i have 10 columns in my dataset and why there are 9 when converting is because one column is percentage_increment and it values range from 0 to 100, what i suppose to do with this column?

Comment: @Ibocus these are **fake** data to simulate yours to demonstrate that this code works, edited with data similar to yours.

Comment: @s_t, it works, thanking you very much :), i owe you this

Comment: @ibocus you're welcome, I've edited with the real data published above, if you need it.

Comment: @s_t, is it normal that when adding up the values of the confusion matrix, the total is 85 and though i have 284 records in my dataset

Comment: Yes because you're predicting only the test dataset, which: `length(pred);
nrow(test_set8);` are equal to 85, so you're predicting for each row of test, training the model on the training dataset.

Comment: @s_t , you are absolutely right, i just got confused.. thanks a lot for making it crystal clear for me.. thanks :)

Comment: @s_t, i was just wondering where did you accumulate this huge amount of knowledge, is it possible to share your story

Answer (score 1):

Provide some example data when asking questions in future.

The code below creates a confusion matrix using the example from [`predict.xgb.Booster`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/xgboost/versions/0.90.0.2/topics/predict.xgb.Booster)

```r
library("xgboost")
data(agaricus.train, package='xgboost')
data(agaricus.test, package='xgboost')
train <- agaricus.train
test <- agaricus.test

bst <- xgboost(data = train$data, label = train$label, max_depth = 2,
               eta = 0.5, nthread = 2, nrounds = 5, objective = "binary:logistic")
## Predict class probability for new data
pred <- predict(bst, test$data)
## Use arbitrary cutoff of 0.5 for classifier
table(test$label, as.numeric(pred > 0.5))
#        0    1
#  0   825   10
#  1     9  767
```